# Which tabbed panel combination is better in Wicket in combination with JQuery and KendoUI?

Tags: java, jquery, kendo-ui, wicket, tabbed

Wicket 7.3 together with JQuery and Kendo (through com.googlecode.wicket...) provides different tabbed panels and items. Which combination is better?

```
TabbedPanel with AjaxTab
```

or

```
AjaxTabbedPanel with AbstractTab
```

What are the advantages or problems? Or is even the combination of an AjaxTabbedPanel with AjaxTab the perfect one?

Are there any examples for this combinations? I want to create a tabbed panel on which tabs can be added and removed dynamically with changing titles as well.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Wicket doesn't provide `AjaxTab` class!

There are two classes with such name in Wicket JQuery UI project. They are integrations with JQuery UI and Kendo UI respectively.

I haven't used them but I'd bet the jQuery/Kendo ones are more sophisticated. Wicket provides the base functionality.

Comment: OK. I got the point about AjaxTab. Nevertheless I am still curious about which combination has what advantages?

Comment: I cannot accept referencing to the API as an answer. The API does not really tell me about the differences of these two variations.

Comment: Then add JQueryUI and KendoUI tags to your question because AjaxTab is not in Wicket scope